# Is there any way to get access to all android notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, pushbullet

I mean if I want to get access to all notification coming in notification drawer. Just wondering how pushbullet and other wearable accessories does that ? Reading all your notifications and pushing them to web servers / particular devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotificationListenerService, which requires permission BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE.

Here is Link 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

and sample code for reference
https://github.com/pgajbhiye/NotificationsSample